# Is a negative index_id in the innochecksum results normal?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, corruption

We're running MariaDB 10.1.38 on Linux with innodb_file_per_table on. When I run `innochecksum -v -S /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`, the summary results show as below. I'm concerned about that last line with index_id "-4294967296". Is that normal or a sign of corruption?

A brief background: We had some generator failures a few months back and this server went down hard a couple of times. It seemed to be running ok for a while after that but then mysql started crashing in a loop, wouldn't start at all. Doing some checks revealed hundreds of corrupt pages in ibdata1. I'm attempting to fix it by deleting ibdata1 and the ib_log* files, then restoring the dbs from backup. So far I've restored the "mysql" database only, and it looks ok but this negative id from innochecksum doesn't seem right.

If it's abnormal, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any support.

UPDATE: I've uninstalled and reinstalled MariaDB. /var/lib/mysql/ was deleted during this process. Immediately after the install I ran innochecksum and it still showed the same entry in that list. So maybe it's normal after all, or a bug in that version of MariaDB. I also did an innochecksum on a MySQL 8.0 server, but it doesn't show the same type of data in the summary so I couldn't compare.

```
Additional information:
Undo page type: 13 insert, 0 update, 0 other
Undo page state: 0 active, 13 cached, 0 to_free, 0 to_purge, 0 prepared, 0 other
index_id        #pages          #leaf_pages     #recs_per_page  #bytes_per_page
1               2               2               7               550
2               2               2               31              2016
3               2               2               9               627
4               2               2               15              653
5               2               2               7               235
11              2               2               0               0
12              2               2               0               0
13              2               2               0               0
14              2               2               0               0
15              3               3               2               109
16              3               3               2               111
17              1               1               0               0
18              1               1               4               390
19              1               1               1               67
-4294967296             1               1               0               0
```

Comment: Strange.  That is -2^32.  It cannot be stored in a 32-bit number.

Comment: That's interesting that it's exactly 2^32, good point. Almost seems intentional in that case. Also see my update in the question - same entry is still there after a reinstall, so it seems that it may be normal.

Comment: Consider posting a bug on jira.mariadb.com